# Detecting deadlocks with DBI

Tags: perl, dbi

What is the proper way to detect a deadlock with Perl DBI?

Should I use `eval { }`? Which exception to catch?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is going to depend on the DBMS.

Some DBMS may not spot the deadlock at all; you'd have to put some sort of timeout on the DB operation, and it is not clear what state DBI and the relevant DBD will be in if the timeout fires.

Some DBMS will detect the deadlock and report an error, in which case you handle the error more or less as you would any other error — but special error code handling for the 'deadlock error' depends on the specific DBMS in use.

I'm not sure whether there are any other significant options.